# Window. Showdialog() throws error

Tags: wpf

I have one application in my windows 10 machine in which i have used the following code to call a window

Window.Showdialog()

it works fine. but in windows xp it throws null exception while calling window.Showdialog(). Its really strange! what may be the issue?

Comment: Bit difficult to help without any sample code / xaml of your dialog

Comment: Post the Stacktrace that might help

Comment: Compile your program in x86 and try.

Comment: window.ShowDialog can return null in some circumstances. Is the return value from that throwing the exception or is `Window` the object that's null and throwing the exception?

Comment: I found the reason the style that i have used in that XAMl cause the issue. before i have used like below Style="{StaticResource  CheckBoxStyleNew}" now i have changed that to Style="{DynamicResource  CheckBoxStyleNew}" now its working fine. Still i have no idea why it doesn't work with xp alone?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused since Windows XP does  not have  any version of the .NET Framework pre-installed in it.
Or you’re having an older version of the framework installed in XP rather than the latest framework it was used to develop the application.

Please update the framework through Microsoft using https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39257
If newest versions are not supported in XP, try considering development of your application using an older framework for it to work in Windows XP.